# ContentProvider empty after bulk insert

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, bulkinsert, android-contentresolver

This is not the first time I am building ContentProviders. But this is the first time I am encountering this problem and I am not sure what to do to resolve it.

I make a bulk insert which returns count as 4. Then immediately I make a query for everything and the query returns count 0. I am not deleting anywhere. Any ideas what might cause this?

It’s as if the data entered into the ContentProvider is mysteriously lost somehow. Actually, here is the bulkInsert code

```
@Override
public int bulkInsert(Uri uri, ContentValues[] values) {
    final SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    final String tableName = DogContract.DogEntry.TABLE_NAME;

    db.beginTransaction();
    int count = 0;
    try {
        for (ContentValues value : values) {
            long id = db.insert(tableName, null, value);
            if (0 < id) count++;
            Timber.d("insertion id: %s",id);
        }
    } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
    }
    Timber.d("successful bulk insert for count: %s",count);
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return count;
}
```

And the query

```
private Cursor getAllDogs(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        Timber.d("Call to get all getAllDogs");
        SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        return db.query(DogContract.DogEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `setTransactionSuccessful` before ending the transaction, otherwise the `endTransaction` call will do a rollback (or not commit).

> ```
> db.beginTransaction();
> ...
> try {
>     ...
>     db.setTransactionSuccessful();
> } finally {
>     db.endTransaction();
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks. I have never had to do that before. Where does it go? after 'db.endTransaction`. How come it worked in the past?

Comment: It works. But I have never had to do this before. Is this a new rule?

Comment: @NouvelTravay this is not new, maybe in the past you didn't do a beginTransaction?

Comment: No. I always did it the same way in the past. In fact I copied and pasted from an existing code that is working in production right now. So maybe it has to do with devices.